# Improper Integral concerned to gamma function

Tags: improper-integrals, gamma-function

As we known, the gamma integral
$$ \Gamma (\alpha) = \int_0^\infty x^{\alpha-1} e^{-x} dx. $$
Now, I would like to know how to reduce the following integral to this gamma integral (or give a concerned expression which allows us to calculate its value),
$$ I(\alpha) = \int_0^\infty  x^{\alpha-1} e^{-x} \ln x dx. $$
Any comment?

Answer (score 3):

Since, when differentiating $x^{\alpha-1}$ with respect to $\alpha$, you get $x^{\alpha-1}\log x$, what you have got is the derivative of $\Gamma(\alpha)$. It is connected with the [polygamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function) function, which is a special function. In your case
$$
I(\alpha)=\Gamma'(\alpha)=\Gamma(\alpha)\psi^{(0)}(\alpha).
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, mickep.

Answer (score 1):

The integral is the Laplace transform of $x^{\alpha-1}ln(x)$ which is :
$$\Gamma(a)p^{-1}\left(\psi(a)-\ln(p)\right)$$
in the particular case $p=1$
$$I(\alpha)=\Gamma(a)\psi(a)$$
$\psi$ is the digamma function.